# List items wrapping too early with position absolute

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation bar that centres itself on the screen using position: absolute;

I am finding that the list items are wrapping to the next line way too early. For example if the with of the nav bar is 500px, I would expect it to not wrap until the screen width reaches 499px but seems to be wrapping way before that.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Find us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4d4d4d;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

#nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#nav ul li:first-of-type a {
    border-left: none;
}

#nav ul li:last-of-type a {
    border-right: none;
}
```

I have created a JSfiddle demonstrating this problem which you can find here http://jsfiddle.net/7bWyM/

As you can see, the list items are wrapping to the next line when there is still a lot of space for them to use up.

My questions are;

1) Why is it not using up this space? I would expect it to all stay on one line until the screen gets too small to fit it on.

2) How can I get around this issue? I cannot set a width as I do not know how many nav item there will be and I want the width to automatically adjust to what is inside (as I does already when using position absolute as the div is no longer a block level element)

Comment: Are you using `position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` Only to center the menu or do you have other reasons for using it? There are other ways to center the menu.

Comment: @Mathias The position: absolute adjusts the width of #nav to perfectly fit around the items leaving no extra spacing on the right hand side, other than that it is just to centre it on the screen

Comment: I suggested a different solution for centering the menu in my answer. It has better support in older browsers, compared to using `transform`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `display: inline-block;` on `#navbar` and `text-align: center;` on its parent to center the menu. Then you woudn't have to use `position: absolute; left: 50%`

It doesn't work in IE7 but since your are using `transform` now, I am guessing that won't be a problem.

## [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bWyM/2/)

```
#navbar_parent {
    text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Works a treat, I feel stupid for not thinking of this. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons I can see from *your* fiddle:

1. The `#nav` is positioned at 50% from the left. It means if the list items are more, they will have to wrap down, because it cannot grow beyond.
2. The right and left paddings on `#nav ul li a` is 35px. Which means there is a gap of 70px in between. So even if you think that there is much space left, there isn't.

***Solution***:

Reduce the `left` position of the `#nav` at an approximate percentage.
And/Or 
Reduce the left-right padding on the `#nav ul li a`.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/7bWyM/1/***

***CSS***:

```
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    ...
}

#nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px 15px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for the needs of my project. The position, left and transform properties on #nav are strictly there to centre it on the page, using this leaves it too far to the left

Comment: It just can't be in centre with that positioning. `left:50%` means it start from the half of the screen. If it starts there, how can it be centre.

Comment: Because the transform: `translateX(-50%);` pulls the nav back by 50% of it's width, resulting in it being centred